# Using ArcGIS to quantify sink volume in glacier bed ("sink" and "fill" tools)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology

I am trying to identify sinks/overdeepenings in glacier beds and quantify their volume.

If you take a look at my data (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT?usp=sharing), you can somewhat make out the overdeepenings in the bedrock below.

I want to quantify these overdeepenings regarding their extent and volume. I've tried using the hydrological tools of the Spatial Analyst, but I'm stuck. I have so far:

- created a flow direction raster
- identified sinks using the "sink" tool. [image: identified sinks]

However, the "sink" tool only gives me a raster with small dots all over, seemingly without the original cell values. How can I get the overdeepenings as a whole? I've read that the "fill" tool might be useful, but how do I proceed?

Comment: Fill and do Con(Filled>original, 1) . This will give your outline of depressions. Region group them and run zonal statistics as table on original. Average depth will be zmax-zmin etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I am fairly new to ArcGIS and have never worked with the "Con" tool before. Could you maybe explain in a little more detail what the needed rasters are and how to get the expression right?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I thought I needed the result of "sink" to run "fill", but I used the original raster instead and it worked.